# Probability of flipping a coin 7 times and having no 3 consecutive heads

Tags: probability, combinatorics

There are $2^7$ possible strings using characters $H,T$. Of those strings, we can count how many have exactly $3, 4, 5, 6,$ or $7$ heads and subtract them from the total to give us the number of valid strings. Is this the right approach, if so, how would I go about computing it?

Comment: The binary strings of length $n≥3$ without $111$ must begin with one of $0, 10, 110$ so you can count them recursively.

Comment: @shrizzy: Counting *consecutive* heads is a different problem from counting heads.

Comment: Your approach has the potential pitfall of counting the sequence $1110111$ twice.

Comment: A straightforward approach (at least if you're a computer programmer) is to enumerate all 128 possible strings from $\{ H, T \}^7$ and discard any that contain the substring `HHH`.  It turns out that there are 81 of these, making the probability $\frac{81}{128} = 0.6328125$.  I assume you want a non-"brute force" solution, though.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A_n$ be a sequence without $3$ consecutive heads,

then it can be
$A_{n-3}\;$ followed by $THH$, or
$A_{n-2}\;$ followed by $TH$, or
$A_{n-1}\;$ followed by $T$

Thus $A_n = A_{n-1}\; +A_{n-2}\; +A_{n-3}$
and we can see that $A_0 = 1, A_1 = 2, A_2 = 4$

Proceed

Comment: @Shrizzy: Has this not served your purpose ? If yes, clear it, no ?